# How do I validate minimum value (age) in template driven angular?

Tags: angular

As the title says, i need some validation on minimum value. I have tried the following:

```
      <mat-form-field class="w-100">
        <input matInput type="number" required placeholder="Age" #age="ngModel" ngModel name="age" min="50"/>
        <mat-error *ngIf="age.errors?.required">Age is required.</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="age.errors?.min">You have to be at least 50 to join.</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

you already have added min="50" , so user cannot enter minimum than 50. Min is a restriction on input and not an error, so you might need a custom validator added and link it to your input like in this [link](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) and have the custom error to output your custom message.

Answer (score 0):

min html attribute on input doesn't cause any error in age but input becomes invalid.

using formControl will solve this issue.

```
    <input matInput  type="number" required placeholder="Age"  name="age" min="50"  ngModel [formControl]="ageControl"/>

   <div *ngIf="ageControl.errors?.min">You have to be at least 50 to join.
  </div>

// in ts
this.ageControl= new FormControl("", [ Validators.min(50)])
```

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrvqzq) repo for the same. Remove the formcontrol and notice that input becomes red when value is less than 50, but no error is thrown.